# glassfish invalid resource

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I am creating a simple JPA project in eclipse to run on glassfish. I get the following error:

```
cannot Deploy GuardApplicationEAR
Deployment Error for module: GuardApplicationEAR: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Invalid resource : jdbc/_default__pm. Please see server.log for more details.
Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method : java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : jdbc/_default__pm
Invalid resource : jdbc/_default__pm
```

I do not have jdbc/*default*_pm defined anywhere in my project. Can somebody please help out. Thanks.

Comment: You have posted the same question on another forum

Comment: Yes, I have asked the same question in the glassfish forum. Do you have any ideas as to what is causing this problem?

Comment: Check if the JDBC connection pool and resource are correctly set up in your Glassfish server's administration console. This error usually occurs if you want to use a jdbc resource which is not there on your server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time. I have installed mysql and stated using that instead of the db that came with glassfish. It seems to work fine now.